# First it says everyone had their own language; but then it says all spoke one before being split

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-noach

First, in [Noach, pasuk Chof perek Yud](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8174/jewish/Chapter-10.htm), it says:

> אֵ֣לֶּה בְנֵי־חָ֔ם לְמִשְׁפְּחֹתָ֖ם **לִלְשֹֽׁנֹתָ֑ם** בְּאַרְצֹתָ֖ם בְּגֽוֹיֵהֶֽם׃

Then again a few pasukim later, pasuk Lamed Aleph:

> אֵ֣לֶּה בְנֵי־שֵׁ֔ם לְמִשְׁפְּחֹתָ֖ם **לִלְשֹֽׁנֹתָ֑ם** בְּאַרְצֹתָ֖ם לְגֽוֹיֵהֶֽם׃

So everyone is split according to their own language.
But in the [next perek](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8175/showrashi/true#v1) it says one language:

> וַיְהִ֥י כָל־הָאָ֖רֶץ **שָׂפָ֣ה אֶחָ֑ת** וּדְבָרִ֖ים אֲחָדִֽים׃

So which one is it?

Comment: Not an answer, but it's interesting to note that _Yonasan_ (pseudo) doesn't render _lilshonosam_ in 10:31 (though he does in :5 and :20).

Comment: While there may be a commentary that addresses this, in my opinion you don't have a question at all, because the Torah is not in chronological order.

Comment: It is interesting the the first two use _lashon_ while the second uses _safah_. Perhaps, while they used different tongues, they were still intelligible to one another.

Comment: To put it another way, this might be implying that language did evolve in different directions before Babel, but that is not to the exclusion of a shared mode of communication between all of mankind. In that case, God's interference at Babel would have been to remove this common language, not necessarily to create many new ones. Although these are just my musings, a cursory glance at the psukim doesn't reveal any contradiction.

Comment: Hod you cant say that on your own there has to be a mesorah for it so if you could find one a pirush who says it and post it It would be appreciated

Comment: What @Hod said (about the Torah not being in chronological order) is common knowledge, no? In this case, I see where Daat Mikra says this, and I believe I've seen the same explanation elsewhere too.

Comment: CR Jonathan Sacks deals with the question of the languages at http://www.chiefrabbi.org/ReadArtical.aspx?id=1823 - not a classical approach.

Comment: Simchashatorah. It is common knowledge that the Torah is not in chronological order. Your question is predicated on a false assumption, namely that because the pasuk comes later, it must have happened later. At the very least, you should first ask "are these pesukim in chronological order?", and then continue with your question.

Comment: you cant say that about everything it can only be applied in certain places

Answer (score 7):

[Rabbeinu BeChaye says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30834&pgnum=82) that the Passuk is telling us that these 10 sons of Cham (if you count them you'll see 11, but one merged with one of his brothers) became the 10 Canaanite nations. Their names here are the names given at birth, but the names we are more familiar with were given once their languages got split up, after the Great Separation. [Bereshit 10:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8174/showrashi/true#v10197) is telling us that the new names they got were based on the languages that they started speaking after the Tower of Bavel.

Why is it telling us this? We should know that the Land of Israel was deliberately given to slaves (the sons of Canaan were the slaves of Shem) because slaves cannot own anything, and therefore have no claim on the Land of Israel. (Rashi to [Bereshit 12:6](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8176/showrashi/true#v6) tells us that the Canaanites conquered the land from the sons of Shem)

Comment: how does this answer the question

Comment: that "according to their languages" is referring to the future.

Answer (score 4):

Excellent question!
Radak to [10:5](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/10.5#e0n7) (איש ללשונו כי לא היו כולם בני לשון אחת אחר הפלגה) and RDZ Hoffman to [10:31](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/10.31#e0n7) (ללשנתם – ביטוי זה מופיע כאן ברשימת העמים על שם העתיד לבוא, אחר פיזורה של האנושות על פני הארץ, המתואר להלן.) address this, and they say that it is speaking about in the future. (In my opinion, this works especially well with Ibn Ezra's understanding of the story of the Dor Haflaga.)

Answer (score 4):

[Rabbenu Hayyim Paltiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Paltiel_(Paltiel_of_Falaise)) to Genesis (11:1) suggests that originally everyone spoke all seventy languages. Later, they each lost the ability to speak all but a a single language. Accordingly, originally there were multiple languages, but the Torah nevertheless says that they were of "one language", since they could all speak with each other.

Answer (score 3):

They had their own languages but also universally spoke Hebrew.  The Confusion removed comprehension of the latter from all but Ever's descendants.  I'll find the source for this b'n.

Comment: See also my answer at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/the-oldest-language/9046#9046, although I don't know a source for it either.