# How many languages were used by Shem's descendants?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, language, parashat-noach

Parshat Noach, [10:31](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8174#v=31&showrashi=true):

> These are the sons of Shem, after their families, after their languages,
> in their lands, after their nations.
>
> אֵלֶּה בְנֵי-שֵׁם, לְמִשְׁפְּחֹתָם **לִלְשֹׁנֹתָם**, בְּאַרְצֹתָם,
> לְגוֹיֵהֶם

The posuk after the next one, [11:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8175#v=1&showrashi=true):

> And the whole earth was of one language and of one speech.
>
> וַיְהִי כָל-הָאָרֶץ, **שָׂפָה** אֶחָת, וּדְבָרִים, אֲחָדִים

[Another question on this site asks why first it says everyone had their own language but then it says all spoke one language before being split](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/first-it-says-everyone-had-their-own-language-but-then-it-says-all-spoke-one-be); see answers there.

However, the difference between the wording is not addressed there:

What is the difference between **שָׂפָה** and **לָשׁוֹן**?

Comment: Note also 10:5 and :20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/first-it-says-everyone-had-their-own-language-but-then-it-says-all-spoke-one-be/88270#88270) to [First it says everyone had their own language; but then it says all spoke one before being split](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/first-it-says-everyone-had-their-own-language-but-then-it-says-all-spoke-one-be), we see that at the very least Radak (Bereishis 10:5 and here) and RDZ Hoffman understand them to mean the same thing.  Many other [Mefarshim to Bereishis 11:1](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/11.1#e0n7) understand the same way (see Ralbag Biur Haparsha, Ibn Ezra I as examples, as they both say this clearly).

However, Ri Bechor Shor has a fascinating understanding of Safah Achas:

> ויהי כל הארץ שפה אחת ודברים אחדים – שהיו כולם יודעים ע׳ לשון.

Meaning, that all of the nations understood all 70 languages, and as a result, Safah would mean they could all understand each other's speech, but not the same language. (Rabbeinu Chaim Paltiel also adopts this approach.)  Also, see R. Hirsch who comments similarly:

> וכיחס "לשון" ל"שפה" - בהוראה המוחשית - כן גם בהוראה המופשטת. **השפה היתה אחת, אך הלשונות היו שונות**, הוה אומר: הם דיברו שפה אחת בדיאלקטים שונים.

I would love to check various translations, but I do not have many available to me at this point. Hope the above helps.