# Are the seventy distinct languages and nations listed?

Tags: history, gentiles, language, parashat-noach

It's a well known concept that there were 70 nations and 70 original languages. Is there any agreement about which ones they were/are? I found [this](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11382-nations-and-languages-the-seventy) which lists the nations, but I'm interested in languages also, and knowing if there is disagreement about this issue among the commentators.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/what-effect-did-migdal-bavel-have-on-world-languages http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15366/is-hebrew-the-mother-of-all-languages-spoken-today-in-the-world

Comment: also see answers [to this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26988/did-chazal-know-about-china-and-the-chinese-and-from-which-of-noachs-sons-do-t)

Comment: Well, in France they speak French; in Spain they speak Spanish; I assume in [Almodad](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0110.htm#26) they spoke Almodadese.

Comment: Can you source how you know there were precisely 70 "original" languages? What do you even mean by "original"?

Comment: @DoubleAA The link I gave above from the [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11382-nations-and-languages-the-seventy) gives these sources:(Soṭah 36b; "Yalḳ. Re'ubeni," section "Miḳḳeẓ," p. 71b).(Shab. 88a; Ex. R. v.; comp. Acts ii. 5).(Tosef., Soṭah, viii.).(Sanh. 17a; comp. Meg. 73b; Men. 65a).

Comment: Also the article itself counts as a source.

Comment: @user85686 That link doesn't discuss "original languages" which is the term I inquired about.

Comment: Since that link died, [here's the archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20140702100035/http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11382-nations-and-languages-the-seventy).

Comment: @Scimonster Turns out you just have to remove the www.

Answer (score 1):

The number 70 in the time of Chazal was a "typological number" meant to convey a generic large number, much like people today use the term "millions" even if they do not actually mean that many.

Thus, you find in the Talmud many instances of the number 70 which are clearly not meant to be exactly 70:

> ... המנבל פיו ומוציא דבר נבלה מפיו אפילו נחתם לו גזר דינו של **שבעים** שנה
>   לטובה
>
> ... א"ר אלעזר בן עזריה הרי אני כבן **שבעים** שנה ולא זכיתי שתאמר יציאת
>   מצרים בלילות
>
> ... כשם שהזית משכח לימוד של **שבעים** שנה כך שמן זית משיב לימוד של **שבעים** שנה

You can find many such instances in the Tanach as well:

> **שִׁבְעִים** מְלָכִים בְּהֹנוֹת יְדֵיהֶם וְרַגְלֵיהֶם מְקֻצָּצִים
>
> מַה-טּוֹב לָכֶם--הַמְשֹׁל בָּכֶם **שִׁבְעִים** אִישׁ כֹּל בְּנֵי
>   יְרֻבַּעַל, אִם-מְשֹׁל בָּכֶם אִישׁ אֶחָד
>
> וְהָיָה מִקֵּץ **שִׁבְעִים** שָׁנָה, יִפְקֹד יְהוָה אֶת-צֹר, וְשָׁבָה,
>   לְאֶתְנַנָּה

In all of the above, 70 is meant as a general term for "many", not a specific number, so that searching for a specific list of all 70 languages is rather futile.

Comment: But if you count the nations enumerated in Parshat Noach, there are actually 70, each of which presumably has a language.

Comment: @Scimonster to support your claim, there are exactly 70 bulls scarified on Sukkos. Which are (as commonly known) for 70 nations.

Comment: @jutky, you are free to interpret as you wish, I think my views are still supported by an unbiased textual analysis.

Comment: Now if you had a specific source that said the 70 nations wasn't specific ...

Comment: @Scimonster - see the Yalkut Shimoni Parsha 58 [9:19]. He counts 74 but 4 were righteous so they were not scattered, leaving us with 70.