# How holy is Aramaic?

Tags: hebrew, language, aramaic

I've always thought that Hebrew is the *Lashon HaKodesh*, the language G-d speaks, and the language of Judaism. And that Aramaic is also important but somewhat secondary.

But based on [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15376/11052) answer, it seems that Aramaic may be as important as hebrew (or even more). How could Aramaic be the first language spoken? What's the importance of Aramaic in Judaism and how does it compare to Hebrew?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: Probably a good place to start: [Megillah 8b](http://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.8b.34)

Answer (score 3):

The גמרא מגילה דף ט says that according to one opinion that allows a sefer torah to be written in aramaic the reason is because it says יפת אל' ליפת which means god glorified יפת by making his language holy.
On the other hand the גמרא סוטה דף לג says that one who is not praying with a quorum should not pray in aramaic because the angels do not understand, tosfot  שבת יב asks that how could it be they dont understand if they know even a persons thoughts? the רא'ש answers that of course angels understand aramaic but rather they dont want to listen or deal with aramaic because its DISGUSTING !!!

rabbi menashe klien in משנה הלכות ח'יג ס'קמז explains (based on the kuzari that says how abraham would speak in aramaic whenever he needed to discuss mundane matters, and in לשון הקודש for all holy matters ) why adam spoke in aramaic and not (לשון הקודש) because he did not want to use the such a holy language like לשון הקודש for mundane matters.

Yet the רמ''א ס' ק''ל brings the בראשית רבה that says one should respect aramaic חודא like we see god respected it by using it in the torah!!!