Source for beginning Creation with the alphabet
I recall a number of years ago hearing the same idea from two different Rabbis, both without citing sources which I would like to now try to find.
When the Torah begins "Bereishis bara Elokim es", it uses the word es to denote an additional idea or item. In this case, since it consists of the first letter of the alphabet followed by the last, it alludes to the idea that G-d began the creative process by creating the alphabet. Using the alphabet G-d proceeded to create the spiritual and the physical realms, alluded to by the Heavens and the Earth.
I have a suspicion this is discussed Tikkunei Zohar directly, but I was not able to find it, and neither one of the Rabbis was able to recall a clear source, even though both confirmed that this is true.
Could you help to find the source?
Thank you very much for your help.

https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Vayechi.75.781?lang=bi&with=all

https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.54a.17

@DoubleAA not a contradiction. The language in Pesachim is ksav, while commentary I am looking for specifically talks about letters (as ideas for example), not writing them.

@Sholom This Zohar is exactly what I needed. If you write it up as an answer, I will be happy to accept it. Thank you so much!

@gt6989b I'm not sure what "letters as ideas" means different from ksav

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Letters as ideas can be viewed as development of Alphabet from hyeroglyphs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_alphabet. However, meanings of roots as discussed by Munk in his book certainly provide a much wider set of meanings by comparison.

Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9036
