Was the world really created by the Hebrew letters?
There’s a somewhat-famous Kabbalistic concept, recorded first in the Sefer Yetzirah, that Hashem created the world by using the letters of the Hebrew alphabet.
Assuming Hebrew indeed evolved from an older language, how should this be understood?
Obviously, this is an extremely esoteric idea within Kabbalah, and I’m not asking for a complete explanation. Nevertheless, I hope it’s possible to explain this one facet—namely, what the Hebrew letters have to do with anything—if Hebrew as we know it didn’t evolve until much later (as per the above assumption).

Did Hebrew evolve much later than 6k years ago?

I don't think the assumption is compatible with the teaching?

Sefer Yetzirah takes position that the alphabet was revealed to Avraham who applied it to all languages including Hebrew. It is not incompatible with the fact that Hashem used the alphabet to create the world, let the humans learn their lessons without ability to communicate using alphabet, and only then revealed it to Avraham.

Assuming Hebrew indeed evolved from an older language. Why would one make such a strange assumption?

@DoubleAA The very first evidence of Proto-Northwest Semitic is from the third millennium BCE, and the earliest inscriptions that might be proto-Canaanite are from around the 10th century BCE.

@shmosel I find archeological evidence for such an assumption supported by Biblical Hebrew itself, as well as evidence from events, claims, and traditions in Tanakh and the Talmud. It’s never explicitly stated, and I could be persuaded to change my stance; but until then, this is the assumption I’m going to make.

@RabbiKaii I agree. I asked this question because I, like most Jews, accept the major Kabbalistic texts as authoritative, and also accept the major Kabbalists of the past and present; and I seek to reconcile this with my position as stated in the above comment. If this is impossible, I’ll have to become a Kabbalist myself to have an educated opinion, and that will take years.

@Qwertrl if I tell you a program from 60 years ago was written in c#, you wouldn't need to be an advanced coder to know that I said something wrong. So, I don't think you can hold both positions? I am not aware of any Rabbonim who would, like you, agree with the authority of Kabbalah, and simultaneously agree with the secular view of history, and the evolution of human civilisation. They seem to all take the account of the Torah and our overall lore pretty literally. See if you can get Reb Yaacov Deane to comment on this question - this is his forté

@RabbiKaii I take the account of the Torah “pretty literally” too. Although there is conflict between the modern understanding of archeology and the most common traditional interpretation of the Torah’s account of human history, this doesn’t change my opinion specifically regarding the origin Hebrew.

@Qwertrl do you have some sources that back up your opinion from such Rabbis? I am curious. Hebrew evolving is new to me in that context, but this site tends to teach me new things quite regularly, which is why I find it hard to leave!

@RabbiKaii [cont’d] And I completely agree with your first metaphor, but I don’t think it’s perfect for this situation: It’s not a good idea to assume anything in Kabbalah, unless a Kabbalist specifically teaches you how it should be understood; and as of now, no Kabbalist has done so to me. Thus, I take all interpretations of this Kabbalistic idea—including my own—with a very large grain of salt. I now believe that the interpretation in which “Hebrew letters” literally means Biblical Hebrew, isn’t correct, so I’m seeking a different interpretation. Even this assumption may be wrong.

@RabbiKaii Not any specifics, but the evidence—external and internal—is difficult for me to disregard, especially the more I learn. Obviously, the Torah prevails in any conflict with the secular understanding of archeology, but the archeological findings are still there, and must be explained.

similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76721/759

I feel uncompelled by archaeology. Personally, I can perceive an all-powerful Creator creating a world in which His Presence is not provable. In such a world, a Creator would create an "old world" in a ready-made state, similar to how Adam was not created as a newborn baby but rather as a full-grown adult. In such an "old world" an all-powerful Creator seeking to hide the His Presence would create archaeology that would obfuscate the truth, in order to give credence to atheism. This would give people the opportunity to choose to believe, rather than be compelled into it by logic and evidence.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/145693/source-for-beginning-creation-with-the-alphabet?noredirect=1#comment487665_145693

@Yehuda That is just "last thursdayism" and archaeology never tried to compel anyone out of it so you are right that archaeology isn't compelling against it. Archaeology just accurately describes what we see is the way the world looks like it came about. The rest is philosophy.

@Yehuda as I mentioned, I believe that the findings of archeology in this regard is supported by evidence from within our tradition, and by certain traits of Biblical Hebrew. And anyway, this assumption is explicitly the basis of the question.

Sorry for throwing a monkey wrench into the discussion. Have you ever heard that the DNA is made out of 22 amino-acids, which function in a way similar to letters of Hebrew alphabet as described in Sefer Yetzira? https://www.amazon.com/Genetic-Code-Hebrew-AlphaBet/dp/9659249748/ref=sr_1_2?crid=1FRP6TDHLJVKY&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.f0aCctePBC2VHek8m3G31wUFpws55A7gq0jjKWgQ2gY.fMB5CzXcrRKneW2JnhotyMgHgolzGFDg834UTqJ_4_A&dib_tag=se&keywords=Erez+Grinboim&qid=1730485639&s=books&sprefix=erez+grinboim%2Cstripbooks%2C68&sr=1-2

Your first paragraph is accurate and correct. Your assumption in the second paragraph is wrong. Your third paragraph assumes the subject to be “extremely esoteric”, which is contradictory to the fundamental idea that all Torah, including Kabbalah, is true. It deals with actual reality, just like natural sciences strive for. You suggest you are familiar with the content of Sefer Yetzirah and the beginning of that text provides you with your answer, if you comprehend it in the original Hebrew. Specifically chapter 1, mishnah 1.

@YaacovDeane If you think my second paragraph is wrong, you have two options: A) convince me that you’re right, because I formerly took your stance, and it takes a lot for me to change my opinion on things like this. B) Din’t answer. The second paragraph’s assumption is part of the question’s premise.

@YaacovDeane “esoteric” is defined as …understood by only a small group, especially one with specialized knowledge… with “mysterious” being a synonym. This is a perfect description of the accessibility of Kabbalah: Only wise, intelligent, mature, extensively knowledgeable adult Jews can understand it, and only when taught firsthand by a Kabbalist, either one-on-one or is small groups. It’s not for everyone to study in-depth. Trying to fully understand the texts without a teacher is dangerous, and can lead to absurd conclusions, even to the point of אֱפּיקוֹרֻסוּת. So yeah, pretty esoteric.

I am quite familiar with the dictionary definition of esoteric. Sefer Yetzirah, to a large extent, is actually a book on basic and essential Hebrew grammar. The opening chapter discusses how one is to conceive of the Hebrew letters in a more complete and mature way. Like Philon (Yedidyah HaKohen of Alexandria), the Tanna, records about Jewish education of children in his day, proper grasp of grammar and the language is essential to understanding anything in Torah.

@YaacovDeane It’s more about pronunciation than grammar, but yeah. I’ve read it. However, that’s not what’s under discussion. We’re talking about the idea that reality was created via these letters, not about their pronunciation as described in the ס״י.

Your understanding of Sefer Yetzirah as expressed in your comment is missing a great deal. There is much more there than simply pronunciation. That “much more” is the answer to your specific question asked here. Perhaps you should try reviewing that first chapter with some of the classic commentaries and then take time to reflect on what you are learning. Consider what you read in the context of physics, physical chemistry and astronomy for example.

@YaacovDeane You claimed that “the Sefer Yetzirah, to a large extent, is… {about} Hebrew grammar”. I stated tangentially that you’d have been more accurate if you’d said “pronunciation” instead of “grammar”. I never claimed that this was what the entirety of the book was about, nor did I even indicate such an intent with my wording. In fact, the whole reason you even brought up the Sefer Yetzirah in the first place, is because my question claims that the relevant Kabbalistic idea is found within it!

@YaacovDeane [cont’d] And the Sefer Yetzirah doesn’t provide me with an answer. All it does is describe the aforementioned Kabbalistic concept (as I said in the first sentence of my question). Mentioned nowhere in the entire Sefer is how the concept goes together with the evolution of Hebrew.

The concept that Hashem used letters to create the world does not originate in kabbalistic works, but it is mentioned in Gemara B'rakhos 55a:

Rav Yehuda said that Rav said: Bezalel knew how to join the letters with which heaven and earth were created. From where do we derive this? It is written here in praise of Bezalel: “And I have filled him with the spirit of God, in wisdom, and in understanding, and in knowledge, and in all manner of workmanship” (Exodus 31:3); and it is written there with regard to creation of heaven and earth: “The Lord, by wisdom, founded the earth; by understanding He established the heavens” (Proverbs 3:19), and it is written: “By His knowledge the depths were broken up and the skies drop down the dew” (Proverbs 3:20). We see that wisdom, understanding, and knowledge, the qualities with which the heavens and earth were created, are all found in Bezalel.

Therefore, we have to conclude that the ancient languages could have used the same sounds, and the divergence between them occured historically due to merging or slight modification of sounds. This could have occured due to the fact that climate, nutrition and lifestyle in different parts of the world causes people develop differently.  The shape of Hebrew letters is not really relevant - it could have been received prophetically or developed independently from Proto-Sinaitic hyeroglyphs or cuneiform.
The fact, that letters were used to create life is a very deep concept which can also be found from the science of DNA, where functionalities of 22 key amino-acids can be broken along the lines of the letters of Hebrew alphabet. For example, Erez Grinboim wrote a book exploring the connection The Genetic Code of the Hebrew AlphaBet.
